GPU black screen after tweaking monitor refresh rates and resolutions in Nvidia control panel
I have a problem with my Display/GPU. So, my monitor supports 60hz by default and 75hz in lower resolutions. I tried making custom resolution in Nvidia control panel for native resolution(1080p) and 75hz. It worked well but now for some reason im having blackout whenever I boot up(It displays Win11 logo and after that goes completely black).
I tried safe boot and it got me on recovery screen saying somethings wrong with my PC. Then, I switched to integrated GPU by intel (using VGA via motherboard and using DP via GPU) and it works fine on 60hz default mode. Now I went and installed fresh drivers because i think that was the issue and I plugged GPU back in and same thing happened. Im not sure if some settings remained from previous build or something but yeah still the same issue. I dont think its the hardware issue because my GPU(gtx 1650) ran at below average clock and at 60 celsius temps. Its also not a display issue because it runs normally until the loading screen on display port and here on vga also runs fine so its not cables either.
All started with idea of going to 75hz and thats when I noticed anomalies. Now, its in 60hz mode on integrated GPU so its back to normal, and even when I was testing initially it would show black screen occasionally so I knew it was not very stable from the get go. I use Windows 11, VGA integrated GPU, DP dedicated GPU, overrun drivers didnt work so I uninstalled everything from Nvidia. When plugged in GPU spins the fan normally and when plugged into motherboard without display port to monitor it shows up in the device manager near the integrated GPU. Served me well for 2 years at much higher temperatures so I know its not faulty on hardware side because the issue started with me trying out software.
PC specs:
i3 8100
GTX 1650
8GB DDR4
Asus motherboard (H310 unsure)
Monitor Lenovo LEN T2224dA
Display port for dedicated GPU
VGA for integrated GPU (My motherboard doesn't have display port and my monitor doesnt have HDMI)

UPDATE: Completely deleting drivers solves the issue, upon installing latest ones again the issue shows up mid-installation (no, its not from the driver install process because  the monitor shows up "power saving mode" which means its completely turned off and not just tweaking display during installation). I used "clean-install" method but I think it picked up something again because this driver is already a week or so old and GPU worked just fine on it before.
